# combining two nsstrings on rss reader example

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, rss-reader

I am using something like this example as my base if you want to look at the code:

[Advanced RSS Reader](https://github.com/icanzilb/Advanced-RSS-reader)

And i am working with GTMNSString+XML and GTMNSString+HTML.

my problem is in RSSItem.m.

it already includes GTMNSString+HTML.I added GTMNSString+XML.

if i use gtm_stringBySanitizingAndEscapingForXML it does what it needs to do
`NSString* description = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...",   [self.description substringToIndex:100]];
    description = [description gtm_stringBySanitizingAndEscapingForXML];`

If i do gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML it also does it.

```
NSString* description = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...",   [self.description substringToIndex:100]];
description = [description gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML];
```

What i want to do is combine it so that it goes through both gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML and gtm_stringBySanitizingAndEscapingForXML. I tried to do this but it didn't work:

```
description = [[description gtm_stringBySanitizingAndEscapingForXML] gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
NSString* description1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...", [self.description substringToIndex:100]]; description = [description gtm_stringBySanitizingAndEscapingForXML];


NSString* description2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...",   [self.description substringToIndex:100]];
description = [description gtm_stringByUnescapingFromHTML];

NSString* finalString=[description1 stringByAppendingString:description2];
NSLog(@"%@",finalString);
```

Comment: I tried that it completely ignored both with that. I think it might be the line underneath it this:   [articleAbstract appendAttributedString:
     [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: finalstring]];

Comment: ok, can you try using stringWithFormat inspite of using stringByAppendingString in the final string line??